# Probability event problem

Tags: probability, probability-theory

If a probability distribution on $A = [0,\infty)$ is given by $F(x) = 1 - e^{-0.1x}$, what is the probability of the event $[3,\infty)$?

Comment: @Henry Thx. ${}{}$

Answer (score 0):

Note that your distribution is a cumulative distribution.  You need to distinguish it from a mass distribution-can you see how?In this case, the value of the distribution at $x$ is the probability that the event is less than $x$, so take $1-F(3)$

Comment: Thank you, that helps a great deal

Comment: @Henry:  you are right, I was backwards.

Answer (score 0):

$F\left(x\right)=P\left\{ X\leq x\right\} $ and you are asked to
find $P\left\{ X\geq3\right\} $.

Here $P\left\{ X>3\right\} =1-F\left(3\right)$.

But we have a continuous distribution here wich means that $P\left\{ X=x\right\} =0$
 for every $x$ so we also have $P\left\{ X\geq3\right\} =1-F\left(3\right)$

In general $P\left\{ X<x\right\} =F_{-}\left(x\right)$ where $F_{-}\left(x\right)=\lim_{z\uparrow x}F(z)$
and we deal with a continuous distribution iff $F$ and $F_{-}$ are
the same functions.